# Values not showing on the DataGridView

Tags: c#, datatable

I have created a data table and added some values to the data table. Using following methods.

Creating of Datatable:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable
        {
            Columns = {
                { "Expenses per day",typeof(decimal) },
                { "Incomes per day ",typeof(decimal) },
                { "Expenses",typeof(decimal) },
                { "Incomes",typeof(decimal) },
                { "No of days",typeof(int) }
            },

            TableName = "Report"
        };
```

Adding data to table:

```
  DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
  row["No of days"] = Convert.ToInt32(no_of_days);
  row["Incomes per day"] = Convert.ToDecimal(average_in);
  row["Expenses per day"] = Convert.ToDecimal(average_ex);
  row["Incomes"] = Convert.ToDecimal(average_in)* Convert.ToInt32(no_of_days);
  row["Expenses"] = Convert.ToDecimal(average_ex)* Convert.ToInt32(no_of_days);
  dt.Rows.Add(row);
  dt.AcceptChanges();
```

DataGridView Code:

```
dataGridView3.DataSource = dt;
```

But it only shows Expenses per day and Incomes per day values in the datagrid.I've added breakpoint for the `AcceptChanges()` and checked the all variables there. All the variables are fine but `row`is not showing other variables except values of Expenses per day and Incomes per day.What's causing this?

Comment: What is the value of the DataGrid property _AutoGenerateColumns_?

Comment: I haven't configured that.So It is default value.

Answer (score 0):

After correcting some typos on your `Incomes per day` column name, I didn't encounter any problem with your code:

[image]

Make a new form and paste this in, see if yours looks like mine:

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var dataGridView3 = new DataGridView();
            dataGridView3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.Controls.Add(dataGridView3);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable
            {
                Columns = {
                { "Expenses per day",typeof(decimal) },
                { "Incomes per day",typeof(decimal) },
                { "Expenses",typeof(decimal) },
                { "Incomes",typeof(decimal) },
                { "No of days",typeof(int) }
            },

                TableName = "Report"
            };


            var no_of_days = "1"; var average_in = "1"; var average_ex = "1";

            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["No of days"] = Convert.ToInt32(no_of_days);
            row["Incomes per day"] = Convert.ToDecimal(average_in);
            row["Expenses per day"] = Convert.ToDecimal(average_ex);
            row["Incomes"] = Convert.ToDecimal(average_in) * Convert.ToInt32(no_of_days);
            row["Expenses"] = Convert.ToDecimal(average_ex) * Convert.ToInt32(no_of_days);
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
            dt.AcceptChanges();

            dataGridView3.DataSource = dt;

        }
```

Incidentally, I didn't have the Dock at first so the DGV was small, and at its default size it only shows two columns. I didn't however think that such a basic problem of "did you forget to scroll/size the DGV?" would have been the root cause, but if the scrollbar didn't show up for some reason, it might be leading you down the garden path...

[image]